# View is lost after editing in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, view

I am adding some java script in the document library's view as suggested in [this](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2013/03/freezing-title-row-of-sharepoint-2010.html) post. The output comes perfectly but my problem is that if I edit the view 3-4 times and preview it in browser from sharepoint designer I am getting error as below.

[image]

The changes being made by me is editing the `height` attribute in css as per the browser's pixel according to increase the height.

What should I do? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have corrupted the XSLT somehow.  I would suggest creating a new view and starting over again as it may be quicker than trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the xslt corrupts?
Because it runs successfully for first 3 - 4 times after that it starts throwing error.

Please give suggestions because I don't know much about XSLT..

Comment: SharePoint designer is a funny tool. I suggest to you to revert to the latest working xslt